# "Can't enter break mode at this time"- Run-time error '1004':

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with several different macros assigned to buttons. In all the macros there is a series of codes that are identical and work fine, however in one of my macros I am getting a Run-time error '1004': Apllication-defined or object-defined error. I don't understand how when this same code works in 3 other macros in the same workbook. Can someone help mayb

I haven't tried a lot because I don't know whats wrong exactly. I did go back into one of the working macros and copy and paste the code from it directly into this one thinking maybe something got messed up while I was adding new code, but it didn't work. I've walked through the code step by step and I know exactly where it occurs but I can't figure why.

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 27")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 28")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 29")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 30")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 33")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Shipping").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Job Intake Form").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Summary Pricing").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

It happens between the True and False after "Job Intake Form"
The intended results are that these tabs are deleted from my workbook. It deleted the shipping tab & the Job Intake Tabs then I get the error. And like I said this same code works perfectly find in 3 other macros in this workbook.

Comment: Are you positive that `Job Intake Form` *do* exist when macro is running? Or may be there's misspell?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 27", "Button 28", "Button 29", "Button 30", "Check Box 33")).Delete`  
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`  
`Sheets(Array("Shipping", "Job Intake Form", "Summary Pricing")).Delete`  
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: You can probably do with just once instance of turning alerts on/off. No need to turn if off only to immediately turn it right back on!

Comment: And on which sheet are the buttons located? More specifically, the button that's running this code?

Comment: I know the Job intake form exists. It successfully deletes it then the error occurs before it deletes the Summary Pricing. And I know it's spelled correctly and matches since it works in the other 3 macros. The button is located on a sheet called estimate title which does not change name or get deleted. thank Gserg I will try this also.

Comment: Thank you GSreg. this worked. I am not sure how it worked or was really different, simpler clearly, but overall the same but it worked. Thank you.